# publish/process makes the SwingWorker slow

Tags: java, swing, process, publish, swingworker

I've tried out to use a SwingWorker to update a progress bar. Nothing new for me. I was a litte bit lazy so I didn't override the process method. Here a simplified example:

```
protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {
    for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
        progressBar.setValue(i+1);            
    }
    return null;
}
```

On me PC it takes about 6 seconds to update the progess bar to 100%. It's Friday so I thought lets do it in a different way like often described. Let's use the publish and process methods to update the progress bar:

```
@Override
protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {
    for (int i = 0; i < maximum; i++) {            
        publish(i+1);
    }
    return null;
}

@Override
protected void process(List<Integer> chunks) {        
    progressBar.setValue(chunks.get(chunks.size()-1));
}
```

But now with the publish method it takes 21 (instead of 6) seconds to update the progress bar to 100%.

*Why?*

Here the entire code (Frame with a 'Start' button and a progress bar):

```
public class Gui extends JFrame {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Gui();
    }

    public Gui() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        final JProgressBar progressBar = new JProgressBar();
        progressBar.setStringPainted(true);

        JButton btnStart = new JButton("Start");
        btnStart.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                new MySwingWorker(progressBar).execute();
            }
        });

        getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout(3, 3));
        getContentPane().add(btnStart, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        getContentPane().add(progressBar, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        pack();
        setVisible(true);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }

    private class MySwingWorker extends SwingWorker<Void, Integer> {

        private final int MAXIMUM = 100000000;
        private final JProgressBar progressBar;

        public MySwingWorker(JProgressBar progressBar) {
            this.progressBar = progressBar;
            this.progressBar.setMaximum(MAXIMUM);
            this.progressBar.setValue(0);
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {
            for (int i = 0; i < MAXIMUM; i++) {
                //----------------------------------
                // TOGGLE BETWEEN THESE LINES:
                //progressBar.setValue(i+1);
                publish(i + 1);
                //-----------------------------------
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void process(List<Integer> chunks) {
            progressBar.setValue(chunks.get(chunks.size() - 1));
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks for suggestions...

Comment: didn't look closely - but your first version is _wrong_ : you _must not_ access a swing component in doInBackground

Comment: yes I know BUT it's working without any issues and it's 70% faster! 6 seconds instead of 21. So the question is for me: What can really happen?

Comment: all the evil thingies that might happen on EDT violations ;-) Hard to detect, spurious (but certain to throw up when you least want it), unpredictable. So simply don't (and most production code should have guards against it). The problem here seems to be that you are flooding the system without need: in a real-world scenario you wouldn't try to update the progressbar with a higher frequency than its screen resolution, would you :-)

Comment: I will check this on my productive system. Analysing 500.000.000 messages. What is the timing difference. Do the user need to wait some minitues more just because of the progress bar? I will check it out..

Comment: my point is that you don't want those millions of notifications: a progressbar filling the screen would have a couple of thousand pixels at most, so wouldn't change anything visible anyway if the notification were too fine grained. The worker doesn't replace brain :-) In doInBackground break it down into reasonable chunks and notify only every 100.000th or so

Comment: There is no performance difference if

Comment: There is no performance difference if something (even for few ms) is done in the loop! But: Millions of notifications will not update the progress bar millions of times, see setValue() of JProgressBar ;) "break it down into reasonable chunks" thats the problem I dont want to invent algorithms for such things. But its working fine: just publish (x%) to the progress bar...

Comment: @a3po : You can certainly go on saying that it works fine; but fact is that the EDT should not be modified from outside the EDT (google "edt java oracle"). You can go ahead and ignore this; but by doing this your code will be broken. I recommend the book "Java Concurrency in Practise" if you'd like to enlighten yourself more on this (and dig into why your code is broken).

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't post every single change but perhaps every 10th:

```
for (int i = 0; i < maximum; i++) {
    doTheWork();
    if(i % 10 == 0) {
        publish(i+1);
    }
}
publish(maximum);
```